# Como usar a função ob_flush() para retornar dados para navegador animadamente?

Tags: php, log

Preciso de um ajuda, tenho sistema de envio de email, preciso saber oque está acontecendo no processo *back-end* um log que retorne para o navegador, ao acionar script, exemplo quero enviar email para 2 pessoas.

Quando um e-mail for enviado ele retorna um `echo '1° Email enviado', '2° Email enviado'` para o navegador seguidamente mas em tempo real tipo barra-de-progresso eu li sobre algumas coisas sobre `ob_start()`, `ob_flush()` mas eu não entendi muito bem, alguém pode me ajuda ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

**PHP:**

```
set_time_limit(0); // coloca o tempo da requisição "infinito"

ob_start();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++): // aqui sera o seu for para enviar o email este envia 10 emails
   echo '|'. $i;  // retornada o email que foi enviado(Ele é acumulativo).
   sleep(1); // substitua pela sua função de envio de emails;
   ob_flush();
   flush();
endfor;

ob_end_flush();
```

**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '../../model/php/teste.php', // arquivo de envio dos emails
  xhrFields: {
    onprogress: function(e) {
      var data = e.currentTarget.response;
      var atual = data.slice((data.lastIndexOf('|') + 1));
      console.log(atual);
    }
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); // resultado final
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
  }
});
```

Veja retornando conforme progresso de envio de emails:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No caso eu tenho um Nginx ele não funciona o flush ?

Comment: Não conheco nginx, ele, você deve procurar por algum metodo que possa pegar o progresso de uma requisição.